# Bind button to observable in Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

Using polymer in Dart I want to observe a value and bind a button to a function that changes it. The following sample code (**test.dart**) should clarify what I am trying to do

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';
import 'package:mdv/mdv.dart' as mdv;

class App extends Object with ObservableMixin {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter => _counter;
  void set counter(int c) {
    print("counter set to $c");
    int oldValue = _counter;
    _counter = notifyPropertyChange(const Symbol('counter'), _counter, c);
  }

  increment(var event) {
    print("increment");
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
}

main() {
  mdv.initialize();

  var app = new App();
  query("#tmpl1").model = app;
}
```

Used with this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <template id="tmpl1" bind>
        <button on-click="increment">{{counter}}</button>
      </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect when the button is clicked that increment inside the **App** class is invoked, but nothing happens. I am sure I am overlooking something simple, as surely this must be possible.

**Note** to run the example code above you do not need to create a **build.dart** file as no custom-elements are being used.

Comment: It seems that the latest SDK (0.6.13.0_r25630) broke something, examples from dart-polymer-dart-examples stopped working with this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I tried to achieve is possible. To get it working you need to include the following in the HTML

```
<script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
```

then the following works

```
 <polymer-element name="x-app">
    <template>
      <button on-click="increment">{{counter}}</button>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

      @CustomTag('x-app')
      class XApp extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
        @observable int counter = 0;

        increment(event, detail, target) {
          print("increment");
          counter++;
          Observable.dirtyCheck();
        }       
      }
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <x-app></x-app>
```

And best of all it works without the need for a build step (i.e. no more **build.dart**).

Answer (score 1):

I have just read the target10 polymer example and I am not sure if you are looking for the kind of solution I am going to post.

1. get Target 10:polymer example from https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/web
2. Insert `<button on-click="increment">{{counter}}</button>` anywhere into one of the divs in xslambookform.html
3. Insert anywhere into xslambookform.dart

``

```
  int _counter=0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  void set counter(int c) {
    print("counter set to $c");
    int oldValue = _counter;
    _counter = notifyPropertyChange(const Symbol('counter'), _counter, c);
  }

  void increment(var e, var detail, Element target) {
    print("increment");
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
```

1. Run slambook.html and press your button. See in console:

   increment

   counter set to 1

   increment

   counter set to 2

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this example seams to depend on build.dart. Something which my example does not use. I was under they impression that external builds where only needed if you make custom elements.